# Bingo game: color table cells of drawn numbers on the generated bingo card

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a simple Bingo game where random numbers are drawn from a pool and then checked if they are on the randomly generated 6x6 bingo card.

In the 7th column and the 7th row of the bingo card, the script counts how many drawn numbers are found in that row or column. When all the numbers in a row or column are drawn, the cell in the 7th row or column will contain 6. When it reaches 6, there is bingo.

So far this seems to be working. The last things I have to add is a green background to the cells in the row or column that caused the bingo. See example:

[image: Bingo card with green background on the bingo column]

Current situation:

[image: Current situation with 7th row and column and no green background]

Also I have to hide the 7th column and the 7th row. They are not supposed to show on the screen.

Do you have any suggestions to give a background color the row/column that has reached bingo?
And how could I hide the 7th column and 7th row from the screen?

My current code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

// Seeding
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

// generate numbers for the bingo card
function generateCard()
{

$card = array();


    for ($row = 1; $row < 7; ++$row)
    {

        $card[$row] = array();

        $deck = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

        // add 6 numbers to the row
        for ($rownumber = 0; $rownumber < 6; ++$rownumber) {
            // Random index
            $index = mt_rand(0,count($deck) - 1);

            // Random number from $deck
            $number = $deck[$index];

            // add row to random number (e.g. row 1 and number 8 = 18)
            $card[$row][] = $row . $number;

            // take out current random number so it wont be drawn again
            unset($deck[$index]);

            // Reset the index of $deck, so no unset is chosen
            $deck = array_values($deck);

        }

        // Last column
        $card[$row][] = 0;
    }

    // Last row
    for ($col = 0; $col < 6; ++$col){
        $card[7][$col] = 0;
    }


return $card;
}


$card = generateCard();

// Print card
function printCard($card){ ?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">

    <?php foreach ($card as $index => $rij) { ?>
        <tr> 

            <?php foreach ($rij as $columnIndex => $number) { ?>
                <td><?php echo $number ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<?php }


$getrokkenGetallen = array();

$deck = range(10,69);

$bingo = false;

// Keep drawing numbers till bingo is true
while (!$bingo){

$index = mt_rand(0,count($deck) - 1);

$number = $deck[$index];


if(!in_array($number, $getrokkenGetallen)){

    unset($deck[$index]);

    $deck = array_values($deck);

    $getrokkenGetallen[] = $number;

    // Check if number is on the card
    for ($row = 0; $row < 7; $row++) {
        for ($rownumber = 0; $rownumber < 7; $rownumber++) {
            if(isset($card[$row][$rownumber])){
                if ($card[$row][$rownumber] == $number) {

                    // set color?

                    $card[$row][6] += 1; // Increment col
                    $card[7][$rownumber] += 1; // Increment row
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// check if the 7th column or row contains 6 positive draws (5 for testing)
if(in_array(6, $card[$row]) || in_array(6, $card[$rownumber])){
    $bingo = true;
}
}



if($bingo){

printCard($card);


echo '<p>Drawn numbers are:<br>';
foreach($getrokkenGetallen as $value)
{
    echo $value . ' ';
}
echo '</p>';


echo '<p>Times drawn: ';
echo count($getrokkenGetallen);
echo '</p>';
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Code should work as it is pasted if you want to see how it runs. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: If you want to keep the foreach loop you can use a counter to count the printed rows and don't print the last row. Same for columns. That way you can hide the 7th row and 7th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work:

```
function printCard($card){ ?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <?php   
        $row = 0;
        foreach ($card as $index => $rij) 
        { 
            $row++; 
            if ($row < 7) 
            {?>
        <tr> 
            <?php 
                $column = 0; 
                foreach ($rij as $columnIndex => $number) 
                { 
                     $column++; 
                     if ($column < 7) 
                     {       ?>
                <td<?php if (($rij[6]==6) || ($card[7][$column-1] ==6)) {  echo ' style="background-color:green"'; } ?>><?php echo $number ?></td>
            <?php    } 
                } 
            } ?>
        </tr>
<?php 
       } ?>
</table>
<?php }
```

I had to change this part of the code, because it didn't do a right check for bingo:

```
// Keep drawing numbers till bingo is true
while (!$bingo){
    $index = mt_rand(0,count($deck) - 1);

    $number = $deck[$index];

    if(!in_array($number, $getrokkenGetallen)){

        unset($deck[$index]);

        $deck = array_values($deck);

        $getrokkenGetallen[] = $number;

        // Check if number is on the card
        for ($row = 0; $row < 7; $row++) {
            for ($rownumber = 0; $rownumber < 7; $rownumber++) {
                if(isset($card[$row][$rownumber])){
                    if ($card[$row][$rownumber] == $number) {

                        // set color?

                        $card[$row][6] += 1; // Increment col
                        $card[7][$rownumber] += 1; // Increment row
                        // check if the 7th column or row contains 6 positive draws (5 for testing)
                        if(($card[$row][6] == 6) || ($card[7][$rownumber] == 6)){
                            $bingo = true;
                        }   
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The best place to check for bingo is where you increment the row and column. At that moment there is a posibility that a row or column reaches 6.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is indeed what I was looking for. I notice that sometimes more than 2 rows/columns are green at the same time. Do you have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Because you have bingo on more than one row. I'll check if that is correct or maybe the numbers aren't.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a fix for your multiple row problem. Succes! ;)